# Launchd Wont Run Application

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd

I made an app (tested it works) and I want to make it run every day at midnight. Here is my PLIST file:

EDIT: after using @user3439894's code here is what I put in my PLIST

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.exampled</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>/Applications/Calculator.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I run it using `sudo launchctl load /Users/fbisurveillancevan/Desktop/LaunchMessageText.plist`, it returns nothing. When I try again, it returns `launchctl: already loaded` The daemon/agent appears to be loaded, but does not run

[image]

Comment: You need to read the manual pages for `launchctl` and `launchd.plist` as **LaunchAgents** and **LaunchDaemons** have specific _directories_ (_folders_) they need to be in. Also you can't run an app directly like that. For example, if in **Terminal** you tried to execute e.g. `/Applications/Calculator.app` it would return e.g. `-bash: /Applications/Calculator.app: is a directory` however if you used e.g. `open -a /Applications/Calculator.app` it would open **Calculator**. You might even have to use a _shell script_ to launch your app with the `open` _command_.

Comment: @user3439894 so the problem is that its in the wrong folder

Comment: RE: "so the problem is that its in the wrong folder" -- Yes, that's one issue, but not the only issue. I already told you what another issue it using **Calculator** as the example app. --- Another issue, I forgot to mention, is typically the `Label` _key_ is the same name as the `.plist` _file_ sans the extension.  I'd also would place the app in `/Applications` not on your **Desktop**.

Comment: What do you mean by "Task Manager" -- that's generally a Windows program; I've never seen a Mac version. Also, are you trying to set this up as a Launch **Agent** (runs as the logged-in user), or a Launch **Daemon** (runs as root, independent of user logins).

Comment: @GordonDavisson By task manager i mean Activity monitor, and I want it to be a launchAgent

Comment: Activity Monitor only shows running processes, meaning it'll only show your program *when it's running* (presumably for a short while after midnight, and only after you get the Daemon/Agent file working right). It will not show  Daemons/Agents that're loaded but not curreltly running. Also, by default it only shows processes running under your user ID, meaning it won't show Daemons, only Agents running under your account. To see running Daemons, choose View menu -> All Processes or System Processes.

Comment: Using `sudo launchctl load ...` loads it as a Launch *Daemon*, rather than an Agent. For a GUI app like Calculator, you almost certainly want it to be an Agent. Try unloading it with `sudo launchctl unload ...`, then reload it without `sudo`. Then leave yourself logged in overnight.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I added the image in the OP

Comment: @FBISurveillanceVan What's that an image of? It appears to be clipped, so I can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: @GordonDavisson its the code that I ran to launch the com.example.exampled.plist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In addition to the comments I've made to your OP, use this example to fix the issues you are having.**

- <sup>**Note:** This was done under **macOS High Sierra** and if using **macOS Catalina** there are some changes to the example, which are detailed is a note further below.</sup>

As a test, in **Terminal**, I executed the following *commands*:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
touch com.example.exampled.plist
open -e com.example.exampled.plist
```

Copy and paste the following *example* **PLIST XML** *code* into the opened `com.example.exampled.plist` *file*, setting the `StartCalendarInterval` for a few minutes from *now*, and then save and close it.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.exampled</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
        <string>-a</string>
        <string>/Applications/Calculator.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Hour</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>Minute</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Back in **Terminal**, execute:

```
launchctl load com.example.exampled.plist
```

Now **Calculator** will open at the **set time**, which is set using **24 Hour time**, e.g `0` through `23` for the **Hour** *key*.

---

**macOS Catalina Notes:**

- In a clean install of **macOS Catalina**, `~/Library/LaunchAgents` doesn't exist by default. Use the following *command* before `cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents`:

  ```
  mkdir -p ~/Library/LaunchAgents
  ```
- Due to changes made by **Apple** in **macOS Catalina** the *fully qualified pathname* for the **Calculator** is: `/System/Applications/Calculator.app`

Change:

```xml
<string>/Applications/Calculator.app</string>
```

To:

```xml
<string>/System/Applications/Calculator.app</string>
```

Or as an alternative, just use:

```xml
<string>Calculator</string>
```

- Both methods work.

---

Additional testing was done with an *application bundle* (**myApp.app**) created by me, saved in `/Applications` on **macOS Catalina**, and the following values worked for me:

```
<string>/Applications/myApp.app</string>
```

Or:

```
<string>myApp</string>
```

---

**Note**: The use of `sudo` is required when dealing with **agents** and **daemons** that are in the designated locations other then `~/Library/LaunchAgents` in order to create, modify, change permissions to make read-only, delete, etc. the **XML Plist** *file* itself. Also note that when using the `launchctl` *command* for **daemons**, `sudo` may be required in some cases, however do not use `sudo` to `load` **agents** with `launchctl`, as it will *load* them as a **daemon**.

To review the *manual pages*, in **Terminal**, use `man command` where `command` is the *commands* **name**, e.g. `man launchctl`, or to more easily read the *manual pages*, just type the *commands* **name** and *right-click* on it selecting: **Open man Page**

If you are going to use **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend you read the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`.

---

Per the *manual pages* for `launchctl` and `launchd.plist` the **PLIST** *files* for **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons** belong in specific directories:

```
FILES
    ~/Library/LaunchAgents          Per-user agents provided by the user.
    /Library/LaunchAgents           Per-user agents provided by the administrator.
    /Library/LaunchDaemons          System-wide daemons provided by the administrator.
    /System/Library/LaunchAgents    Per-user agents provided by OS X.
    /System/Library/LaunchDaemons   System-wide daemons provided by OS X.
```

There is also an *example xml property lists file* at the end of the *manual page* for`launchd.plist`.

Comment: When I run `launchctl load com.example.exampled.plist`, using the `plist` file that you answered, i get the error `invalid property list`

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, Sorry, I accidentally left off the closing `</plist>` _tag_ when I copied and pasted it. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Correction: you generally need `sudo` when dealing with Launch Daemons, and shouldn't use it for Launch Agents; it's not related to where the files are.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson, `sudo` (or being `root`) **is** required to write to or modify files, permission, etc, in all but `~/Library/LaunchAgents` of the locations under `FILES` in the quoted _man page_ excerpt.  Trying to do so without `sudo` (or being `root`) will error out with `Permission denied` or `Operation not permitted` type error messages.

Comment: @user3439894 Sorry, I wasn't specific enough: you need to use `launchctl load` (and many other `launchctl` functions *without* `sudo` when working with Launch Agents, not matter where they're located. If you run something like `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/somefile.plist`, it'll be loaded as a Daemon in spite of its location.

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the help, but It still wont appear in task manager.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, Your title says "Launchd wont appear in task manager" and I assume you really mean **Activity Monitor**. What isn't appearing in **Activity Monitor**? `launchd` most certainly appears there, it is after all the parent of all the processes, sans the `kernel_task` as `launchd` is a child of it. If your looking for e.g. `com.YourUser.RunMyCode` you'll not see it there because it's not supposed to show there! If you want to see all of the `launchctl` jobs loaded into `launchd` then use `launchctl list`, or about a specific job, use e.g. `launchctl list com.example.exampled`.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, My answer shows a proper example of a User Domain Launch Agent to open an application bundle and it works as intended, where your's was not working as `<string>/Users/fbisurveillancevan/Desktop/Earlybird.app</string>` is not the proper way to open an application bundle by a Launch Agent.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks. For some reason my app wont run. I used your code above, and it still wont work. I will edit my question to add what I put.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, Let me ask you this... If you follow the directions in my answer verbatim, and I do mean explicitly and specifically as the directions are written, is Calculator launched at the designated time, the time being just a minute or two from the current time before _loading_ it? If yes, then if you use `launchctl` to _stop_ and _unload_ the `com.example.exampled.plist` to edit in the real app you want to use and adjust the time again a few minutes from now to test, save it and _load_ it again with `launchctl load com.example.exampled.plist`, does it work?

Comment: @user3439894 no, it doesn't. I copy-pasted the whole plist file into the folder that opened  with `open -e com.example.exampled.plist` (after changing directory), and calculator.app will not open. I searched in activity monitor for `calculator`, which shows nothing.

Comment: @user3439894 I edited my original post with more details

Comment: @user3439894 I have read that the files `launchAgents` folder are automatically loaded during login. Would logging out, then logging back in fix anything?

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, First I want to say that for testing purposes if you actually followed verbatim, and I do mean explicitly and specifically as the directions are written, then **Calculator** should have opened at the time you set in the `StartCalendarInterval` _key_, which by the way is in **24 hour time**, and you used `launchctl load com.example.exampled.plist` from `~/Library/LaunchAgents` as the **PWD** and it was loaded before the time set in the `StartCalendarInterval` _key_. There is no need to be looking in **Activity Monitor** as **Calculator** will show on the **Dock**.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, I have gone to a system I've never used before and did exactly what I wrote in my answer, **it worked without issue!** If you can't get this simple example to work then I guess a good place to start is to `unload` the **PLIST** _file_, delete it and then reboot your system, then follow the steps in my answer again and make sure you set the `StartCalendarInterval` _key_ properly and to a time that is a few minutes after what the time is when you `load` the **PLIST** _file_. If then you get **Calculator** to open at the set time you can try it with your app the same way.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks, I will try that. I am running macOS 10.15.3 on a 2019 macbook pro. What did you use for your "test" system?

Comment: @user3439894, If it helps, when I run `launchd list...` it returns:


`{
 "LimitLoadToSessionType" = "Aqua";
 "Label" = "com.example.exampled";
 "OnDemand" = true;
 "LastExitStatus" = 256;
 "Program" = "/usr/bin/open";
 "ProgramArguments" = (
  "/usr/bin/open";
  "-a";
  "/Applications/Calculator.app";
 );
};`

Comment: @user3439894, Also, here is what i did. I ran `cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
touch com.example.exampled.plist
open -e com.example.exampled.plist`, then I copied the above code into the textedit file that opened. then I ran `launchctl load com.example.exampled.plist`, which returned nothing.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, This was doe and tested under **macOS High Sierra**. I'll test this in a while under **macOS Catalina** and see if I run into any issues.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, Okay, I've tested it under as clean install of **macOS Catalina**, not an upgraded install, and I had to do two things. 1. Since `~/Library/LaunchAgents` doesn't exist by default in a clean install, I had to use `mkdir ~/Library/LaunchAgents` before `cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents`. 2. Change `<string>/Applications/Calculator.app</string>` to `<string>/System/Applications/Calculator.app</string>` (but `<string>Calculator</string>` works too) and it worked without issue then. For this example, it's due to the changes **Apple** made to **macOS Catalina**. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @FBI Surveillance Van, I have update my answer to reflect the differences between **macOS High Sierra**, the system the original answer was written and tested under, for a clean build of **macOS Catalina**. Sorry for any confusion and frustration this has caused, but bitch to **Apple** about it. 

Comment: @user3439894 Thanks for the continued help. So glad that it works now. I hope that more people will benefit from this .